# Does data view Subscribers include data from ALL business units?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

Does data view Subscribers include data from ALL business units?

If yes, how to pull our data for one specific business unit only since there is no column for Account ID where MID can be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general, Subscribers view has data from all business units. If you want from a specific BU, write your query in that BU only.

Comment: That's what I am doing...The BU that I am working on is NOT the top level account. So when I am running query in my BU, I do not know if I am getting data from other BUs also or just mine?

Comment: You can try this - Create a new subscriber in some other BU. Note the subscriberkey and then check if its coming out of the query in your concerned BU

Comment: I do not have access to other BUs

Comment: Then try doing some spot checking if you can find any subscriber key which do not exist in your BU ..

Comment: You can also confirm with Premium Support

Comment: I believe subscribers only from Parent BU are accessible through data views.

Comment: How can I make sure the data is only from our business unit  since there is no column for Account ID or BU in Subscribers BU? I basically want to get stats on our subscribers and it seems like default reports in marketing cloud are also pulling data from parent BU which is why I am looking into query. Please advice.